# Can i access a monobehaviour script from within a non monobehaviour script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access a monobehaviour script from within a non monobehaviour script and haven't had any luck yet. These two classes need to stay as they are as changing them will break a lot of functionality so i cant create an instance and cant attach to a gameobject to drag and drop.

Any ideas?

```
public class myClass1 : monoBehaviour
{
  public String text = "hello";
}

public class myClass2
{
  private myClass1 monoClass = new myClass1();

  private void Start()
  {
    Debug.Log(monoClass.text);
  }
}
//THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: You may run into some issues that monobehaviors are designed to be on scene components. As you arent doing that it may not work overly well.. please define how "this does not work"

Comment: Please note that your Start function in myClass2 is NOT called by the Unity Engine automatically. Start is only called by the Engine on MonoBehaviour classes.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, but...

You can't call `new` on any script that inherits from `MonoBehaviour` due to requiring being attached to a game object. So you can't *create* references, but you can absolutely pass them around:

```
public class myClass1 : monoBehaviour
{
  public String text = "hello";
}

public class myClass2
{
  private void Start(myClass1 mc1)
  {
    Debug.Log(mc1.text);
  }
}
```

Now, `myClass2#Start` is going to be difficult to call in this example, but it will compile.

I do stuff like this in my projects all the time. I usually have one class that is a MonoBehaviour component that's attached to the main camera with a [static instance field](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/Main.cs#L26) that I can reference from anywhere else, though most of the non-MB scripts don't deal with Unity objects most of the time (they only hold data and one of the manager classes handle updating game objects with that data by maintaining a dictionary between them).

Though [sometimes](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/items/Industry.cs#L58) the object holds its own GO reference  (the result of trying different things to see what worked or wanting to avoid a dictionary lookup--regardless of if it was efficient or not).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the `GetComponent` approach from @Zaine I'd like to throw the singleton pattern into the pool of possible answers:

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private static SomeClass _instance;
    public String text = "singleton text";

    public static SomeClass Instance { get { return _instance; } }
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } else {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }
}
```

It only works if you have exactly **one** of these scripts. But from all other scripts, you can access it easily:

```
public class SomeOtherClass : MonoBehaviour {
     private void Start(myClass1 mc1)
     {
         Debug.Log(SomeClass.Instance.text);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not know you could pass them as parameters. This is good to know, however in my project this wouldn't have worked as I was calling the method from another non-MB script which did not have the the MB script referenced anywhere for me to pass it on.

What I did was create an empty `GameoObject` and attach the script as a component then use the class from there across the non_MB script.

3 lines of code:

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject();
obj.AddComponent<MyScript1>();
MyScript1 myscript1 = obj.GetComponent<MyScript1>();
```

Works great as `GameoObject`s are not restricted to MB.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes What I did is create an `interface` that can receive `Component` object for `Non-Monobehaviour` class.

```
public interface IComponentReceiver<T> where T: Component{
    void AddComponent(T pComponent);
}

public class ExampleNonMonoBehaviour : IComponentReceiver<CharacterController>{
    private CharacterController _cc;
    public void AddComponent(CharacterController cc)
    {
     _cc = cc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).